# Get all items within a site collection using SharePoint Search REST API

Tags: search, rest

How can I get all the items of lists and document libraries within a specific SharePoint site collection using SharePoint Search REST API?

Comment: http://sitecollection/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'&rowlimit='1000'&clienttype='AllResultsQuery' This search show the all site but its don't show private site collection.
Anyone Can brief how to get complete site collection with private site collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could go with this:

```
http://sitecollection/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http:%2f%2fsitecollection+ContentClass:STS_ListItem+ContentClass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=20
```

Replace "sitecollection" with your address (note that there are 2 places where this needs to be changed) and adjust rowlimit to how many results maximum you would like to get.